# Passing link parameter values to form

Tags: php, hooks, forms

I've added **edit|delete** options in every row of a table, created in the admin panel.

```
function column_A( $item ) {
    $actions = array(
        'edit'   => sprintf( '<a href="?page=%s&action=%s&row=%s">%s</a>', 
            $_REQUEST['page'], 'edit', $item['row_id'], 'Edit' ),
        'delete' => sprintf( '<a href="?page=%s&action=%s&row=%s">%s</a>', 
            $_REQUEST['page'], 'delete', $item['row_id'], 'delete' ),
```

When I click on **edit** link, I read on browser:

```
http://.../wordpress/wp-admin/admin?page=myTablePage&action=edit&row=1
```

Now I would like to call the relative form, using values: **action** and **row**.

The forms are placed in the same script, in the function that shows the table page. I've something like this:

```
function myTablePage() {
    ...
    if ( $action == 'edit' ) {
        ?> <div class="wrap">
        <h2>Form edit</h2>
        <form>...</form>
        </div> <?php
    } elseif ( $action == 'delete' ) { 
        ?> <div class="wrap">
        <h2>Form delete</h2>
        <form>...</form>
        </div> <?php
    } else { 
        ("SHOW THE TABLE) 
    }
    ...
} // end myTablePage
```

I tried this code, but I don't understand why it doesn't work.

The functions are independent if they are in one script, so I think it's something like the inability to pass the value, but there could be a lot of reasons that I don't know (for example, if this method of passing link could be unsecure).

What's a good method to pass the `action=edit/delete` link, to a switch case for the form redirecting?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for this question,
I founded the solution, now I know that i'm a dummy.

```
if($_GET['action'] == 'edit')
```

for everyone has my same drama.

(the question remains open for better suggestions about doing that, in the best and most secure way)

Tank you for any suggestion.